# Any way to make GCP VM machines user-independent?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine, google-iam

I want to have VM instance that contains installed libraries/dependencies accessible for different users. I grant the roles like Compute Admin, Service Account User etc. for the users accordingly. Although they can see the folders/files/codes from the shared home folder, they can't use the installed libraries and other drivers for instance.

Every user has to access with his SSH key and I don't want them to install packages and drivers from scratch. Is it possible to accomplish?

Comment: Yes it is possible if you install previously the packages or using a tool to configure the VMs like Ansible

Comment: yes you can do it, you might also want to use service accounts in managing your users, if you want them to assign specific roles and restrict your users activity.

Comment: The first step is to take away their **sudo** privileges so that they cannot overwrite system installed packages. However, your strategy will be a problem to manage. Use separate VMs for each user.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Suggestion for handling login

You could modify the user roles for those to have compute login on the instance and follow the instructions on [setting up os-login](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/oslogin/set-up-oslogin) to allow them to SSH via gcloud (using their own accounts).

### Suggestion for handling the common dependencies

You can create a [custom OS image](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/images) based on one of the supported images that you use and bake the dependencies into that custom image.

**Or**

Use a [startup script](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/instances/startup-scripts/linux) to install/grab dependencies at startup.

As John said in the comments, you want to ensure your users don't have SUDO privilege as they could impact others.